# Using Django's admin interface to upload large file to GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, file-transfer, blobstore

I've been trying to find a way to upload a large file to GAE's datastore using Django's admin interface, but haven't found an answer that specifically addresses this issue. I'm fairly new to Python/Django, so there might be an angle that I'm not looking at.

I've been looking at the [django-filetransfers](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers) solution, but I'm not sure how to integrate that into the admin interface. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I haven't tried to implement anything yet, as I'm unfamiliar with the admin interface, with regards to extending default behaviour.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you're uploading? Is it just one big file? Maybe static hosting would be better. Also, are you using django-nonrel or some other django-GAE binder?

Comment: I'm hoping to upload about 100MB video files and serve them via GAE. Yes, I am using django-nonrel.

Answer (score 2):

File uploads to the appengine are handled using the blobstore and not the datastore.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App

The datastore filesize limit is 1 megabyte.  So, attempting to upload a large file into the appengine's non-relational database isn't going to work.  This is by design.

The documentation I provided above shows you how to implement large file uploads.